# CRTP and templated expressions

Tags: c++, templates, expression, crtp

In a complex library that uses templated expressions, and the Curiously Recursive Template Pattern (CRTP), I need some overloaded operators to be specialized with base classes, but operations involving their derived classes are not finding the base-class specialization.

Ie:

- if an operator is defined for BaseA< T > + BaseA< T >, then code DerivedA< T > + DerivedA< T > finds the operator no problem.
- if an operator is defined for BaseB< T > + BaseB< T >, then
  code DerivedB< T > + DerivedB< T > finds the operator no problem.
- but if an operator is defined for BaseB< BaseA< T > > + BaseB< BaseA< T > >, then
  DerivedB< DerivedA< T > > + DerivedB< DerivedA< T > > is NOT finding that operator.

How can I make sure the operator for the specialized, nested case is found?

I can restate the problem thus:

**If I have classes (using CRTP)**

```
template<typename derived, typename datatype> class BaseA;
template<typename derived, typename datatype> class BaseB;
template<typename datatype> class DerivedA : public BaseA<DerivedA<datatype>,datatype>;
template<typename datatype> class DerivedB : public BaseB<DerivedB<datatype>,datatype>;
```

**and I have an operator**

```
template<class derived1, class derived2, class datatype>
operator+(const BaseB<derived1,datatype> &bb1,const BaseB<derived2,datatype> &bb2);
```

**it will happily be used to solve the function
DerivedB< DerivedA< double > > + DerivedB< DerivedA< double> >, eg**

```
DerivedB<DerivedA<double> > A;
DerivedB<DerivedA<double> > B;
A+B;
```

**but if I have a more specialized operator for the same operation instead**

```
template<class bderived1, class aderived1, class datatype, class bderived2, class aderived2>
operator+(const BaseB<bderived1,BaseA<aderived1,datatype> > &bb1,const BaseB<bderived2,BaseA<aderived2,datatype> > &bb2);
```

**this operator is not found by the same function**

```
DerivedB<DerivedA<double> > A;
DerivedB<DerivedA<double> > B;
A+B;
```

***How can I ensure the specialized operator will be found for solving this function?***

I have attached mimalistic code to reproduce the problem, only the one line
BA1+BA2;
does not compile with g++.

Full code example:

```
//uses templated expressions

//uses CRTP, see
//http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern
//http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern

//g++ problem.cpp -o problem

#include <iostream> //cout, endl
#include <stdlib.h> //EXIT_SUCCESS

using namespace std;


//TypeC
template<class datatype1, class datatype2>
class TypeC{

    public:
    TypeC(const datatype1 &d1,const datatype2 &d2){
        cout << "helloC" << endl;
    };
};

//BaseA
template <typename derived, typename datatype>
class BaseA{

};


//DerivedA
template <typename datatype>
class DerivedA : public BaseA<DerivedA<datatype>,datatype> {

};

//operator for BaseA+BaseA
template<class derived1, class derived2, class datatype>
TypeC< BaseA<derived1,datatype>,BaseA<derived2,datatype> >
operator+(const BaseA<derived1,datatype> &ba1,const BaseA<derived2,datatype> &ba2){
    return TypeC< BaseA<derived1,datatype>,BaseA<derived2,datatype> > (ba1,ba2);
};

//BaseB
template <typename derived, typename datatype>
class BaseB{

};


//DerivedB
template <typename datatype>
class DerivedB : public BaseB<DerivedB<datatype>,datatype> {


};

/*for reasons outside the scope of this example, operators for BaseB<> op BaseB<> need specialization, cant use the general case:
//operator for BaseB+BaseB
template<class derived1, class derived2, class datatype>
TypeC< BaseB<derived1,datatype>,BaseB<derived2,datatype> >
operator+(const BaseB<derived1,datatype> &bb1,const BaseB<derived2,datatype> &bb2){
    return TypeC< BaseB<derived1,datatype>,BaseB<derived2,datatype> > (bb1,bb2);
};
*/

//operator for BaseB<double>+BaseB<double>
template<class derived1, class derived2>
TypeC< BaseB<derived1,double>,BaseB<derived2,double> >
operator+(const BaseB<derived1,double> &bb1,const BaseB<derived2,double> &bb2){
    return TypeC< BaseB<derived1,double>,BaseB<derived2,double> > (bb1,bb2);
};

//operator for BaseB<BaseA>+BaseB<BaseA>
template<class derived1, class derived2, class Aderived1, class Aderived2, class datatype>
TypeC< BaseB<derived1,BaseA<Aderived1,datatype> >,BaseB<derived2,BaseA<Aderived2,datatype> > >
operator+(const BaseB<derived1,BaseA<Aderived1,datatype> > &bb1,const BaseB<derived2,BaseA<Aderived2,datatype> > &bb2){
    return TypeC< BaseB<derived1,BaseA<Aderived1,datatype> >,BaseB<derived2,BaseA<Aderived2,datatype> > > (bb1,bb2);
};




int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    DerivedA<double> A1;
    DerivedA<double> A2;

    A1+A2; //knows this DerivedA+DerivedA is equivalent to BaseA+BaseA, hence calls "operator for BaseA+BaseA"

    DerivedB<double> B1;
    DerivedB<double> B2;

    B1+B2; //knows this DerivedB<double>+DerivedB<double> is equivalent to BaseB<double>+BaseB<double>,
    //hence calls "operator for BaseB<double>+BaseB<double>"

    DerivedB<DerivedA<double> > BA1;
    DerivedB<DerivedA<double> > BA2;

    BA1+BA2; //g++ error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘BA1 + BA2’
    //compiler cannot see this DerivedB<DerivedA<double> > + DerivedB<DerivedA<double> > is equivalent to BaseB<BaseA>+BaseB<BaseA>
    //I want it to see this op as equivalent to BaseB<derived1,BaseA<Aderived1,datatype> > + BaseB<derived2,BaseA<Aderived2,datatype> >
    //How can I make BaseA act as a wildcard for DerivedA and any other classes derived from it, in this nested case?

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: is this clause the issue?

Implicit conversions (clause 4) will be performed on a function argument to convert it to the type of the corresponding function parameter if the parameter type contains no template-parameters that participate in template argument deduction.

Comment: I dont think I understand the clause, as Im self-taught and rather incompletely so. Seems to me that operator overloading with templated base-classes works fine for operations with derived class operands, so long as templated operands are not nested. This much compiles perfectly. But I would like to make it work for a derived class nested inside another derived class, and I cant see how to help the compiler recognise the nested derived-class operands as fitting the nested base-classes operator overload?

Comment: @finlaylabs: I am still very basic with templates. 

I think we need to crack why 'r2' is not allowed in C++

BaseB<DerivedB<DerivedA<double> >, DerivedA<double> > &r = BA1;
BaseB<DerivedB<DerivedA<double> >, BaseA<DerivedA<double>, double> > &r2 = BA1;

Comment: Thanks chubsdad for the comments, I too cant see why 'r2' is disallowed. And if its disallowed, how to overcome this?

Comment: @finlaylabs: This is because given class 'A' and it's derived class 'B', and 'X' a function template, and some 'T', X<T, B> is not same as X<T, A>. That is no implicit conversion happens to convert 'B' to 'A' even though 'A' is a base of 'B'

Comment: @chubsdad: It seems to me that while implicit conversions are not taking place, solving of functions of derived-class 'B' by operator overloads defined using base-class 'A', is working because by inheritance 'B' is an 'A'. This happens for the cases A1+A2 and B1+B2 in my code. Somehow using 'base-class' overloaded functions is breaking down for 'derived-class' expressions though when types are nested (used as template parameters). I have tried restating the problem in the parent post, would you mind having a look?

Answer (score 3):

This is because the argument type, `DerivedB<DerivedA<double> >` is not a derived class of `BaseB<bderived1, BaseA<aderived1,datatype> >`: The arguments of `operator+` have for their base class's second template argument passed the type `DerivedA<double>` (which is `datatype`) but the `operator+`'s function parameter specifies `BaseA<aderived1,datatype>` as second template argument.

Since with these many types in there it's quite convoluted, let's make a simplier example

```
template<typename T>
struct B { };

template<typename T>
struct D : B<T> { };

struct base { };
struct derived : base { };
```

Now, let's see how these behave

```
template<typename T>
void f(B<T> const&);

void g(B<base> const&);
void h(B<derived> const&);

int main() {
  D<derived> dd;
  f(dd); // works, like your first case
  h(dd); // works too (just not deduced).

  g(dd); // does *not* work, just like your second case
}
```

The C++ Standard specifies that derived->base conversions are considered when matching a deduced function parameter type. That's why `file << "hello"` works: The operator is defined in terms of `basic_ostream<C,T>` even though `file` really could be an `basic_fstream` (derived class of it). This applies in your first case. But in your second case you try to deduce a parameter that's entirely not a base class of the argument passed.